# java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject where value already converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, google-play-services, google-play-games

It is a question that has been asked many times but i didn't  find any solution from the answers that they gave.

Basically im using the GSON to create instances of classes to JSON in order to serialize them and store it into the cloud save.

Here is the code

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
User user = dbmanager.getUser();
String user_json = gson.toJson(user);
saved_data.put("user", user_json);
```

The dbmanager.getUser(); is an Sql query that collects the user from the android database and return it as an instance of the User class.

Then i'm using the load method to load the data

```
public void converLoadData(String data) throws ParseException
{
    if (data == null || data.trim().equals("")) return;

    try {
         User user = new User();
         data = data.replace("\\\\", "\\");
         JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data);
         System.out.println("data: " + obj.toString());
         JSONObject user_object = obj.getJSONObject("user");
         System.out.println("user " + user_object.toString());
        String last_sync = obj.getString("last_sync");
        java.util.Date db_sync = dbmanager.getLastSync(user.getID());
               }
    catch (JSONException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "Save data has a syntax error: " + data, ex);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Save data has an invalid number in it: " + data, ex);
    }
}
```

The return of the println of data is this one

```
data: {"current":"{\"title\":\"Puzzle
2\",\"fnMoves\":[],\"solution_path\":\"puzzles\/2\/CKqbKz5f\/7b1886a261b0400768e75dea91948576.json\",\"puzzlecolors\":[0,0,0],\"puzzle_path\":\"puzzles\/2\/CKqbKz5f\/41a0b30fdfdf6685dd50c6019391cc00.tmx\",\"level_id\":2,\"locked\":false,\"level\":2,\"puzzle_site_id\":2,\"id\":2,\"score\":20,\"fnkeys\":1,\"solved\":false,\"difficulty\":1.0}","solved":"[{\"id\":1,\"puzzle_id\":1,\"puzzle_tries\":10,\"user_id\":1}]","user":"{\"personphoto\":\"https:\/\/lh4.googleusercontent.com\/-5XfDNwK1PwI\/AAAAAAAAAAI\/AAAAAAAAPs8\/C0onA9lyKvY\/photo.jpg?sz=50\",\"google_id\":\"fdgsdfgfgfgsdgsdf\",\"personname\":\"Test
Test\",\"last_sync\":\"2014-08-18
22:12:12\",\"lifes\":3,\"highscore\":13,\"ID\":1}","last_sync":"2014-08-18
22:12:12"}
```

and here is the error. This error has to do with the data value because i have back slash? i'm passing the data (which is string) into a JSON object and then i'm trying to collect the user element. using this JSONObject user_object = obj.getJSONObject("user"); and this is where i\m having the error. Anyone who can help me please? thank you

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"personphoto":"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-5XfDNwK1PwI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAPs8/C0onA9lyKvY/photo.jpg?sz=50","google_id":"104757400111626678244","personname":"George Panayi","last_sync":"2014-08-18 22:12:12","lifes":3,"highscore":13,"ID":1} at user of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

---

Solution: I'm using "remove" method to remove extra backslashes and quotes which cause bad format of the JSON Object

```
data = data.replace("\\", "");
data = data.replace("\"{", "{");
data = data.replace("}\"", "}");
data = data.replace("\"[", "[");
data = data.replace("]\"", "]");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working by cleaning up the JSON object a bit. I think it's just a bad formatting error.

First, the escape slashes, they need to be uniform or removed. I removed the ones escaping the double quotes, but left them in everywhere else.

Then I removed the double quotes around the nested objects and arrays. "{...}" to {...} and "[...]" to [...]

Seems to be all that was necessary.

```
{"current":{"puzzle_path":"puzzles\/2\/CKqbKz5f\/41a0b30fdfdf6685dd50c6019391cc00.tmx","solved":false,"score":20,"difficulty":1,"level_id":2,"id":2,"fnkeys":1,"title":"Puzzle\n2","level":2,"solution_path":"puzzles\/2\/CKqbKz5f\/7b1886a261b0400768e75dea91948576.json","puzzlecolors":[0,0,0],"puzzle_site_id":2,"locked":false,"fnMoves":[]},"user":{"ID":1,"lifes":3,"google_id":"fdgsdfgfgfgsdgsdf","highscore":13,"last_sync":"2014-08-18\n22:12:12","personname":"Test\nTest","personphoto":"https:\/\/lh4.googleusercontent.com\/-5XfDNwK1PwI\/AAAAAAAAAAI\/AAAAAAAAPs8\/C0onA9lyKvY\/photo.jpg?sz=50"},"solved":[{"puzzle_id":1,"id":1,"user_id":1,"puzzle_tries":10}],"last_sync":"2014-08-18\n22:12:12"}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. yes it's true that the problem was the bad format from GSON.  i fixed it as you told me